# How to show CDockablePane after it has been closed

Tags: c++, mfc

I understand CDockablePanes remember their state when the program is closed and then opened again, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to show a CDockablePane that has been closed in a previous use.

This is my initialisation code :

```
    DWORD dwPaneStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI;
    MyPane.Create(_T("MyPane"), this, CRect(0, 0, 0, 120), TRUE, ID_VIEW_MYPANE, dwPaneStyle | CBRS_BOTTOM));
    MyPane.ShowPane(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);
```

So this would create my pane and then set it to be shown, but for some reason I can't see it in my main frame... What am I missing?

Also, I would like to be able to show the pane when a certain button is pushed. I already have my MessageMap and OnButtonFct() ready. I just need to know how to show the pane.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you purposely mean to give the pane zero width?  Your CRect has zero width.

Comment: I did. Most of the stuff I create, I give a CRect(0,0,0,0) and it fills in the necessary space. I'm certain this is not the problem since I tested with a different pane width and it changed nothing + it was visible before I closed it...

Comment: There's a pretty good CDockablePane article at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493218/Understanding-CDockablePane).  I would read through it so see if you missed anything.

Comment: I found it... it seems MFC saves the entire state of how the program was left in. So when the app is launched, the panel is shown, but then the app loads the last state and hides the panel. I was able to make it visible again by using the same line :

    `MyPane.ShowPane(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);`

on a button push event instead of during the creation.

There seems to also be a way to disable the automatic "Load last state" behaviour, but since I found an easy way to make my panel visible again, I didn't explore it thoroughly.

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Shame I can't answer my question before 8 hours and already have the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it... it seems MFC saves the entire state of how the program was left in. So when the app is launched, the panel is shown, but then the app loads the last state and hides the panel. I was able to make it visible again by using the same line :

```
MyPane.ShowPane(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);
```

on a button push event instead of during the creation.

There seems to also be a way to disable the automatic "Load last state" behaviour by adding the following in the CWinAppEx constructor.

```
m_bSaveState = FALSE;
```